# How to set REST session against RQM server (4.03)

Tags: rest, ibm-jazz

I would like to create an automation script to access RQM and retrieve some information. I would like to access RQM using REST API.

The problem is that all the articles I found ([i.e. modify test in RQM using REST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDqW-Hrx_S0))
indicates that I need to provide session-id as part of the request, but in order to provide session-id I need to manually login first, and that kind of killing of the automation process.

Is there anyway to create the REST session in a way which supports automation scripting?